# How to implement a slide out menu only in the first tab of tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have been trying to add a slide out menu to a tabbar controller. I've been able to add it to all tabs. I want it to function only in the first tab. I am using mmdrawercontroller till now. I've gone through the whole documentation on GitHub   it haven't found any solution.

I'm open to use other slide menus too.
Thanks in advance 
Akshay

Comment: instead of adding the slide out menu to the tab bar controller, why not simply add it to the view controller connected to the first tab?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann  was using mmdrawercontroller and the method to implement the controller needs to make a controller the rootviewcontroller. If I'm setting the first view controller as the root then the tabbar isn't showing up below

Comment: maybe try making `mmdrawercontroller` the first tab view (where the controller's main view is the former first tab view)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Tried that too, then the slide out menu is setting as the first tab of the tabbar and the main view controller on which slide out was to be implemented is nowhere in the picture

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the github repo and I saw that **MMDrawerController.h** has this method

[image]

You could use that to just allow the pan gesture on your first tab.